# Hey i am very new in react i have to do a form validation using 'onChange' and if valid then only state should be change.How to do that in right way?

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, onchange

Hey i am very new in react i have to do a form validation using 'onChange'  and if valid then only state should be change.How to do that in right way?
const [status,setStatus] = useState(false)

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {

   let isFieldValid = false;
  
   if (e.target.name === "user_email") {

    isFieldValid = /\d{1}/.test(e.target.value);
   
  }
  if (e.target.name === "user_name") {
  
  isFieldValid =(e.target.value  !== null) && ( e.target.value.trim() !== '');
  }

  if(e.target.name === 'message'){
 isFieldValid = e.target.value  !== null) && ( e.target.value.trim() !== '');
  }
 
  if(isFieldValid){
    setStatus(true);
  }else{
    setStatus(false);
  }

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can manually validate all input fields but its lots of work and code management, so instead of manually writing logic for validating form you can use the following NPM library, which will help a lot

[react-form-input-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-form-input-validation)

[react-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-validation) (this library follows exact method you currently using )

[react-form-validator-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-form-input-validation)

[simple-react-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-react-validator)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {

   let isFieldValid = false;

   const {name, value} = e.target;
  
   if (name === "user_email") {
      isFieldValid = /\d{1}/.test(value);
   }

   if (name === "user_name" || name === 'message') {
     isFieldValid = value && (value.trim() !== '');
   }  

    setStatus(isFieldValid);
  };
```

Your code is correct, but I have just refactored it like this.
Is it helpful?

You can also use validation node modules.

Example:

```
var validator = require('validator');

validator.isEmail('foo@bar.com'); //=> true
```